# How to handle Google indexing 'pages' that not exists

Tags: php, seo, google-search-console

I build dynamic websites where structure is hierarchically saved in the database (Own CMS). I am using the Adjacency model to manage this database tables (PHP and Mysql through PDO)

I detected that Google is indexing pages that it should not.

**An example of a tree structure used for navigation:**

```
home
  about us
  products
    productgroup 1
    productgroup 2
  contact
    support
    sales
```

Imagine this structure in a pulldown menu with links to the pages. When I select products->productgroup 1 I get a url like www.domain.com/products/productgroup-1 which pulls the data from the database (based on the last uri element: productgroup-1, a slug version of the title) and shows it in my template. I do not query all elements, only the last (I should, I know).

**So far so good. Google is indexing this page as expected:**

```
http://www.domain.com/products/productgroup-1
```

**But... When I use Google webmaster tools I see a lot of pages indexed with 404's, like:**

```
http://www.domain.com/products
http://www.domain.com/contact
```

And so fort.

These pages are empty and have no link in the navigation structure.

I have designed my structure so that these pages return a 404 error. Webmastertools confirms this but keeps indexing these pages. I know I can use robots.txt to disallow Google's search bot to keep it drom indexing url's. Is there another way to do this? Should I generate a 403 instead of a 404?

I am in the dark here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do a few things:

1. Use 301 Permanent Redirection to direct this empty pages to a relevant page:

   - Even if Google does not crawl http://www.domain.com/products,  some people may still access this link by removing the last segment from the URL from the browser.  You probably don't want to show them 404s but some relevant information.
   - For example, you can redirect http://www.domain.com/products AND http://www.domain.com/products/ to http://www.domain.com/products/productgroup-1
   - Learn more about 301 redirection from [Moz](http://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection)
   - It is possible to use mod-rewrite to do 301 redirects instead of doing it at code level.
2. Submit a sitemap to google webmaster tools.

   - This is a definitive list of URLs in your site.
   - Having a sitemap will note remove the list of 404 URLs already indexed on Google, but will inform Google of all your "official" URLs in your site and the intended crawl frequency.
   - Read more from [Google webmaster tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en) here.
3. Check your HTML code for references to "/products"  or "/contact".  Googlebot will not be crawling these URLs otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

301 redirection is the best option which you dont want pages and also you can assign those pages in robots.txt page.